# How to add href of each anchor on click to hidden input of single form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to add the value in the `href` of each `<a href=""></a>`, on click, to a single hidden `<input>` value in a single form. This needs to be dynamic and swap out the href value on each link click.

I need to do this with jQuery ideally.

I'm using WordPress and GravityForms and I'm not sure where to start with this.

Comment: I think you can't do that because hidden field does not show on the page thats why click events not works

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the `href` attribute of the `a` tag

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('a').attr('href', 'your_link');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a>Link</a>
<button>Add link</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it after a while..

```
link.each(function() {
    jQuery(this).on('click', function() {
        href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        input.val(href);
    })
});
```